# Total values of used/second-hand goods sold and donations?

Tags: reference-request, data-request

Are there any good estimates of the total values of

1. used or second-hand good sales
2. donated goods

for the US or any other country?

I know these estimates are generally excluded from GDP, but are they tracked in any rigorous way by some government agency? I searched BEA and FRED, but have come up dry.

Comment: Did you ever find any such statistics?  I was particularly interested in "underground" second-hand sales, e.g. craigslist-type stuff.  [this article](https://www.uschamber.com/co/good-company/launch-pad/retailers-fuel-resale-trend) seems to have a few numbers related specifically to clothing, but it is entirely concerning sales that happen through a business intermediary.

Comment: Unfortunately not, otherwise I would have written up my own answer. If I was doing this now, I would start by looking in the pitch decks or shareholder letters for these companies since they try to do some market sizing.